# Remove Title from DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

For some reason, I have two titles in my DatePickerDialog.

[image: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/8rVEjlv.png)]

How can I get rid of the white title at the top?
This is the code I use to create the Dialog:

```
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(ProfileActivity.this, this, year, month, day);
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().updateDate(year, month - 1, day);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
datePickerDialog.setTitle("");
```

Comment: does this remove the title only ? What If i need the whole whitish title view to be removed

Comment: This will remove the entire header. Working solution!

Answer (score 16):

I found that for myself:
`datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());`

and probably for you:
`datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().updateDate(year, month - 1, day);`

is the culprit. If you leave that line out, you won't have a title.

I'm looking into setting a specific theme tosolve the issue.

-- UPDATE --

Make sure you call `.setTitle("");` AFTER you call `.getDatePicker().x()`. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: This is so freaky. setTitle("xyz") after all other statements worked for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

More appropriate so that it even supports holo versions

```
    datePickerDialog.setCustomTitle(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(ProfileActivity.this, this, year, month, day);
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
datePickerDialog.setTitle("");
datePickerDialog.show();
```

your should add **datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());** and then add **datePickerDialog.setTitle("");**

this type of sequence to remove top white background header

Answer (score 0):

Use this to also hide the title background

```
datePickerDialog.setTitle(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

apply it in your styles

```
 <style name="MaterialCalendarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="materialCalendarHeaderTitle">@style/HeaderTitle_Hide</item>
</style>

<style name="HeaderTitle_Hide" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.HeaderTitle">
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

`AlertDialog` have `setCustomHeader` method, using it and set a custom view with `zero` width, `zero` height. It will work

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
timePickerDialog.setCustomTitle(linearLayout);
```