# Remove and adjust Date Picker in android

Tags: java, android, xml, datepicker

Hey guys having issues with customizing the date picker in android. Here's an image of my current date picker.

[image: calendar]

As I've highlighted in black two things I'm having issues with.

1. Is there away to remove the header of the date picker? I just want the calendar part.
2. Is there a way to adjust the date picker so that it'll fit the width of any screen it's on?

I'm using a date picker not a date picker dialog.

Comment: give your xml code

Answer (score 0):

to remove the header

```
datePickerDialog.setTitle("");
```

see the link,

[Remove Title from DatePickerDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33486643/remove-title-from-datepickerdialog)

to get fullscreen, set android:layout_width to match_parent

Comment: its not a datePickerDialog, it's a date picker itself. And match_parent,fill_parent etc does not work out for the date picker dialog seems to have a static width. Fill parent / match parent only makes the layout match the width but the date picker does not (see image)